# Understanding the segments of a Connection String

Tags: sql-server

Setting up a connection string from an example project I have this:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EssentialApp; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

My question is about the `\\MSSQLLocalDB`
Is this the name of the instance of SQL Server we have installed?

This is the LOCALDB and SQL Instance I have installed on my machine. I want to make sure in my example as I follow I will be using **LOCALDBSERVER** one.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the LOCALDBSERVER named instance your connection string will look something like:

```
"Data Source=.\LOCALDBSERVER;Initial Catalog=EssentialApp; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Take a look at [ConnectionStrings.com/sql-server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), which explains more or less all possibilities.

Comment: Are you sure I don't need the (localdb) part? you gave replaced it with a ".\"

Comment: The .\ stands for the local computer, so yes. You have two named instances of SQL Server Express installed named (SQLEXPRESS and a Default Instance). SqlLocalDb is another edition which you address via (localdb). You wanted to point your connectionstring to your named instance LOCALDBSERVER, which you are about to install as your screenshot shows...

Comment: Any idea why in SSMS for ServerName if I type (localdb)\LOCALDBSERVER  it does NOT connect BUT if I type .\LOCALDBSERVER  it DOES connect fine?

Comment: Yes.. because LocalDb is another instance you have to start manually. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)...